# FindNext - VBA code test is correct but Formula in Excel does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not an expert in VBA, sorry if my question is not clear. We wrote a code which runs and gives the correct result while testing in Module. However when using the formula in Excel it does not give the same result. We've been searching for a solution without success, can you please have a look at the code?

Story: Check if "id" is in the "sheetName"'s A column. If yes then check Column X-Y if the given "priceDate" is within the period. If there are more columns with that "id", check all rows. If found something which is also within the period then give back the entry from column V. If nothing then give 0.

Many thanks in advance!!

```
Option Explicit

Function GetDiscount(sheetName As String, id As String, priceDate As Date)

On Error GoTo onError

Const DISCOUNT_COL = 22
Const FROM_DATE_COL = 24
Const TO_DATE_COL = 25

Dim fromDate, toDate As Date
Dim acol, found As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With Worksheets(sheetName)
    Set acol = .Range("A2:A10000")
    Set found = acol.Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = found.Address

        Do
            fromDate = DateValue(.Cells(found.Row, FROM_DATE_COL).Value)
            toDate = DateValue(.Cells(found.Row, TO_DATE_COL).Value)

            If priceDate >= fromDate And priceDate <= toDate Then
                GetDiscount = .Cells(found.Row, DISCOUNT_COL).Value
                Exit Function
            End If

            Set found = acol.FindNext(found)
            If found Is Nothing Then
                GetDiscount = 0
                Exit Function
            End If
        Loop While found.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

GetDiscount = 0
Exit Function

onError:
    MsgBox err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: btw, the If found Is Nothing Then : GetDiscount = 0 : Exit Function :  End If section does nothing. You've already found it once so you will keep finding it until you loop around to the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we modified the code based on your comment and also based on the linked solution in the other topic! It works finally! Many-many thanks!